# Wordpress + .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, flash

I have page "http://sitename.com/constructor/" 
On this page I insert SWF that located in site root directory named "constr" and this swf should load another swf located in same "constr" folder.
But when main swf try to load second one in firefox network console I see http://sitename.com/constructor/constr/09.swf 404 not found.

what I shold add to htaccess?

Comment: try to use http://sitename.com/constr/09.swf like this.

Comment: yes, in editor I use absolute path. parent sfw that load child swf try load it by http://sitename.com/constructor/constr/09.swf. I need to remove /constructor/ from url

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
constr/09.swf
```

try to call

```
/constr/09.swf
```

Comment: in editor I use absolute path. swf compiled. source lost((

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^constructor/constr/(.*)$ /constr/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```